# Utilizar script de postinstalación «postinst» tras la instalación de un paquete Debian

Tags: ubuntu, debian, shell

La pregunta habla por si sola, pero voy a explicarme porque aún resulta muy ambiguo.

Lo que busco es poder ejecutar el script de postinstalación que proporciona Debian antes de empaquetar los «deb». Digamos que tengo una aplicación que va a guardarse en `/usr/share/` y quiero hacer un acceso directo de ésta a `$HOME/Escritorio` (acceso directo que, en realidad, sería ejecutar un comando `cp` y una vez copiado darle los permisos correspondientes al «*.desktop»).

El principal problema es que no sé en qué momento se ejecuta ni cómo tengo que poner el contenido en éste. Esto es lo que he intentado hacer:

```
#!/bin/sh
# postinst script for myapp

set -e

case "$1" in
    configure)
        cp -i /usr/share/applications/myapp.desktop ~/Escritorio
        chmod 777 ~/Escritorio/myapp.desktop
    ;;

    abort-upgrade|abort-remove|abort-deconfigure)
    ;;

    *)
        echo "postinst called with unknown argument \`$1'" >&2
        exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Directamente no sé si estoy haciendo algo mal, porque instalo el «deb» y nunca ejecuta este script. Si sirve como información adicional, lo hago desde el Centro de Software de Ubuntu, sin usar el Terminal.

Me vendría muy bien vuestra ayuda, y acepto sugerencias. ¡Un saludo!

Answer (score 1):

Fallo terrible por mi parte. He conseguido resolver el problema, y profundizo ahora con la explicación.

Si mi script de postinstalación no funcionaba antes es porque el script nunca llegaba a compilar con el paquete Debian «deb». A pesar de que «postinst.ex» es un script que se me generaba automáticamente para ser editado con el contenido que yo quisiese, no me había documentado lo suficiente como para saber que **el prefijo «*.ex» se trata de un "example" o fichero de ejemplo**, tal y como pone en la [documentación que proporciona Debian](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.es.html).

> Algunos de ellos tienen el sufijo .ex (de «example») en el nombre.
>   [...]
>   elimina los sufijos .ex o .EX de los archivos de plantilla que lo tengan.

Suprimiendo el prefijo de los scripts y recompilando otra vez la aplicación conseguí incluir el script y hacerlo funcionar.

Espero que algún día esta respuesta ayude a alguien tan despistado como yo. ¡Saludos!